# Assigning a column value based on multiple column conditions in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, variable-assignment

I've got a pandas dataframe that is structured as such,

```
ID  Col1  Col2
1   50    12:23:01
1   34    12:25:11
1   65    12:32:25
1   98    12:45:08
2   23    11:09:10
2   12    11:12:43
2   56    11:13:12
2   34    11:14:26
2   77    11:16:02
3   64    14:01:11
3   34    14:01:13
3   48    14:02:32
```

What I need is to be able to search within a repeating `ID` value to find a condition in column 1, say `Col1==34`. Based on this, I need to create a new column, `Col3`, that takes on the corresponding value in `Col2`. The end result I need is shown below.

```
ID  Col1  Col2      Col3
1   50    12:23:01  12:25:11
1   34    12:25:11  12:25:11
1   65    12:32:25  12:25:11
1   98    12:45:08  12:25:11
2   23    11:09:10  11:14:26
2   12    11:12:43  11:14:26
2   56    11:13:12  11:14:26
2   34    11:14:26  11:14:26
2   77    11:16:02  11:14:26
3   64    14:01:11  14:01:13
3   34    14:01:13  14:01:13
3   48    14:02:32  14:01:13
```

I've tried the following, but it's not pulling the distinct `Col2` value, rather it's just duplicating `Col2`

```
df['Col3'] = np.where(df.Col1.isin(df[df.Col2==34].Col1), df['Col2'], 0)
```

I realize that assigning the `df['Col2']` else 0 from the where condition is most likely my logic issue, and that there is probably some easy concise way of doing this (or that my time might be better spent in SQL), but I'm not sure on how to set this up. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using `query` + `map`

```
df['Col3'] = df.ID.map(df.query('Col1 == 34').set_index('ID').Col2)

print(df)

    ID  Col1      Col2      Col3
0    1    50  12:23:01  12:25:11
1    1    34  12:25:11  12:25:11
2    1    65  12:32:25  12:25:11
3    1    98  12:45:08  12:25:11
4    2    23  11:09:10  11:14:26
5    2    12  11:12:43  11:14:26
6    2    56  11:13:12  11:14:26
7    2    34  11:14:26  11:14:26
8    2    77  11:16:02  11:14:26
9    3    64  14:01:11  14:01:13
10   3    34  14:01:13  14:01:13
11   3    48  14:02:32  14:01:13
```

---

***dealing with duplicates***

```
# keep first instance
df.ID.map(df.query('Col1 == 34') \
    .drop_duplicates(subset=['ID']).set_index('ID').Col2)
```

Or

```
# keep last instance
df.ID.map(df.query('Col1 == 34') \
    .drop_duplicates(subset=['ID'], keep='last').set_index('ID').Col2)
```

Comment: Appreciate it! Worked perfectly.

Comment: Actually, this works on a test dataset, but in my actual dataset it appears that I've got duplicated values based on the error:  `Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects`. I am assuming I'll have to drop duplicates first?

Comment: That will work.  But, do you want to take first observation?

Comment: Any of the observations would work, so taking the first would be fine. In my real situation it's as if (sometimes) row 1 (Col1==34 and Col2==12:25:11) is duplicated some number of times, or may not be duplicated at all. I didn't realize I had these duplication's until now (I've got a rather large dataset)

Comment: Thanks for the edit on dealing with duplicates - was extremely helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Take advantage of pandas automatic index alignment by making `id` the index. Then  just append a column based on boolean selection. This answer assumes col1 is unique.

```
df.set_index('id', inplace=True)
df['col3'] = df.loc[df.col1 == 34, 'col2']
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a NumPy based vectorized solution -

```
df['Col3'] = df.Col2.values[df.Col1.values == 34][df.ID.factorize()[0]]
```